# Snowflake NodeJS `snowflake-sdk` response when `fail-open` warning occurs

Tags: javascript, node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake nodejs snowflake-sdk `execute` function has a `complete` property which value is a callback function with the following parameters `err, stmt, rows`

By default the connection is `fail-open`.

What is the shape of the response specifically for `rows` property when a user gets the `fail-open` connection warning as follows:

> ""message":"[8:08:42.842 AM]: WARNING!!! using fail-open to connect.
> Driver is connecting to an HTTPS endpoint without OCSP based
> Certificated Revocation checking as it could not obtain a valid OCSP
> Response to use from the CA OCSP responder. Details:","level":"INFO"}

My execute function integration code looks like this:

```js
connection.execute({
  sqlText: `${sqlQuery}`,
  complete: function(err, stmt, rows) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(`Failed to execute statement due to the following error: ${err.message}`);
    } else {
      rows.forEach((row) => {
        for(let key in row) {
          if(isDate(row[key])) {
            row[key] = row[key] + "";
          }
        }
        //out the data to the console
        console.log(JSON.stringify(row)); <<--- row has to be an array of objects with column names as keys and their valuse
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Because a third party tool I'm integrating with, require `row` to be an array of objects (see the code snippet above) when there is no `fail-open` warning, the shape of the response is send as expected, but when the warning occurs, the response is being malformed.

Unfortunately I'm unable to replicate the issue as I don't have access to the system that returns the mentioned above warning.

Does the `rows` response property contain more properties than just an array of objects with query results when there is `fail-open` warning?

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question but have you tried putting a `console.log(rows)` just before your foreach statement to see what you get?

Comment: I can't speak to the Node.js driver, but nothing changes to the row objects returned through the Snowflake JDBC or ODBC drivers with an OCSP warning. On the surface it sounds like something that if confirmed should probably be reported to Snowflake Support. If you want to see what it's doing in response to an OCSP warning, the code is here: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-nodejs/search?q=OCSP

Comment: Unfortunately I can't `console.log` as this is in an environment I don't have access to, I've tried recreating the issue in my local env, but to no avail